# Initilize an array-like class with something resembling an initializer list?

Tags: arrays, list, initialization, initializer

I have a numerical Vector class, which is a wrapper on a float array, and I am sick of element-by-element initialization:

```
Vector vec(3);
vec(1) = 1;
vec(2) = 2;
vec(3) = 3;
```

Without using C++11 (Boost ok, but not preferable), what operators and tricks can I play to do this all at once, something **resembling** a brace-enclosed initializer list like:

```
Vector vec(3) = {1,2,3};
// --OR--
Vector vec(3) << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

or anything *sane* really.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to give your `Vector` class an `int*` constructor and then initialise it from an int array that you can initialise with a standard initaliser list. So something like this:

```
int vecData[] = {1,2,3};
Vector vec(vecData, sizeof(vecData)/sizeof(vecData[0]));
```

It's not the perfect solution, but probably more convenient than initalising elements one by one.